# Write lambda function as def:-function

Tags: python, function, numpy, lambda

I'm trying to write a lambda-function into a def:-function in order to better understand what is going on in a Python example-script I got. In some function in that script a lambda-function is integrated and I'm wondering what it would look like as def:-statement. (I'm new to using lamda functions)
So here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [18,28,29,32,35,36,37,37,39,40,42,42,46,48,54,56,57,61,61,62,63,65],                  "B":  [9,13,17,15,23,21,24,28,26,30,29,36,38,42,40,48,40,51,54,50,51,57]})

a = lambda df: np.corrcoef(df[:,0], df[:,1])[0,1]
print(a)

>>>function <lambda> at 0x0000016896784950> #result of print-statement

def lamb(df):
    g = np.corrcoef(df.iloc[:,0],df.iloc[:,1])[0,1]
    return g

b = lamb(df)
print(b)

>>>0.974499725153725 #result of print-statement
```

How do I alter the `def lamb(df):`-code so that its print-statement has the same output as the print-statement of the lambda-function?

Comment: You are not printing the same, in one your are printing a lambda function object and in the the other the result of a function call

Comment: I know, that's my question. How do I alter the 'def lamb(df):'-function in order that it prints the same..

Comment: Just: `print(a(df))` in the same way you had `print(lamb(df))`.  Both a and lamb are functions.

Comment: `print(lamb)` ?

Comment: print(a(df)) gives: TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), 0)' is an invalid key

Comment: What insight are you aiming to get by printing the function object?

Comment: In a function of an example script I'm looking at, a parameter is given by a lambda-function but I was wondering how it related to a normal def:-function so as an exercise I was trying to convert it and get the same output and as I repeatedly failed to do so, I put the question up here and @Praveen gave me the answer I was looking for ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print(a)` prints a function, but

```
b = lamb(df)         
print(b)
```

print the output of the function

Try `print(lamb)` to get the similar result

Comment: Jep, that's it! Damn.

Answer (score 1):

With

```
print(a)
```

You're trying to print a function, to have the same usable output:

```
print(a(df))
```

Is what you're looking for

Comment: print(a(df)) gives: TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), 0)' is an invalid key

Comment: Can be a conflict in naming, what happens when you change either the variable name or the parameter in your lambda declaration?

Answer (score 0):

just print the function lamb. this will print the function at location at 0x......

```
print(lamb)
```